# XMLType View column not recognised

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g, oracleforms

Before I port my 6i forms to 11g (as part of a modernization program) I am also testing adding a new piece of functionality which will require the creation of a text document containing XML. I have created a view of XMLType in the underlying database (9.2.0.1.0) to expose the information as XML.
I was trying to use `TEXT_IO` built-in inside forms (I know I will need to replace this with WebUtils `CLIENT_TEST_IO` in 11g)

Any way, here is the `WHEN-BUTTON_PRESSED` trigger code I wrote, but it will not compile.

Forms Builder 11.1.2.0.0 running on Win7 32 bit (A VMWare virtual).

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE
 IN_FILE TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;
 XMLDOC VARCHAR2(4000);
 CURSOR C IS SELECT X.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$.GETSTRINGVAL() FROM SS_CDRS_EXPORT_COMP_XML2 X;
 BEGIN
  IN_FILE := TEXT_IO.FOPEN('C:\CDRSCOMP.XML','W'); 
  FOR C1 IN C LOOP
   TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE(IN_FILE, C1.OBJECT_VALUE.GETSTRINGVAL());
   NULL;
  END LOOP;
  TEXT_IO.FCLOSE(IN_FILE);
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN Others THEN
   NULL;
  TEXT_IO.FCLOSE(IN_FILE);
 END;
END;
```

It gives the error:

```
no column 'SYS_NC_ROWINFO$' in table
```

running the statement:

```
SELECT X.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$.GETSTRINGVAL() FROM SS_CDRS_EXPORT_COMP_XML2 X;
```

in SQLPlus (11.1.0.7.0), it works fine and returns rows.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I changed the view to something like

```
create or replace VIEW SS_CDRS_EXPORT_COMP_XML AS
select 
XMLELEMENT("CM_DATA",
 XMLFOREST(TRIM(V.COMPNAME) AS COMPANYNAME, 
 ....
 ))
AS "RESULT"
```

FROM  v;

and the line in the button press code to ..

```
CURSOR C IS SELECT X.RESULT.GETSTRINGVAL() FROM SS_CDRS_EXPORT_COMP_XML X;
```